# sqlalchemy dump metadata to file

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to dump the metadata info from the DB to a file?

I have a huge table (over 50 columns) and I don't want to do this manually.

I want to create a file like this:

```
class mytable(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'mytable'
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   ...
```

so it will be nice if I can export directly instead like this:

```
mytable = Table('mytable', metadata, autoload=True)

mytable.export('myfile.py')
```

and this will create my file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`sqlacodegen`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sqlacodegen/) to do this. It will even try to guess the relationship between your models.

Basic documentation on [Overview](https://bitbucket.org/agronholm/sqlacodegen/overview) page. Also run `sqlacodegen --help` to see full option list. In your case you might want to specify just one table.

Comment: thanks but I got `TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument '_warn_on_bytestring'`

Comment: got it, i was trying to import a view .. thanks it works

Comment: I just got an error on "collation" on a set field, any idea why?

Comment: No idea. Need more information to check. Which RDBMS do you use?

Comment: I tried: mysql:pymysql and mysql:cymysql and both I get errors for collation, lenght and retrieve_as_bitwise